# A ladder leans against a wall, but the problem asks how long is the ladder.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

here's the problem:

A ladder leans against a wall with its base 10 ft from it. When the ladder is pulled 3 ft further from the wall, the upper end slides down 7 ft. How long is the ladder?

Here's what I've done so far:

First, I did a drawing with the initial conditions. Assuming the right triangle I got:

$a^2+10^2=h^2$; $h$ is the length if the ladder.

From the other conditions, I created a new triangle adding 3 ft to the base, and substracting 7 ft from the other side of the triangle. I obtained:

$(a-7)^2+13^2=h^2$

Then I equaled the equations to get $a$ and got:

$a=\frac{59}{7}$

I went ahead and replaced it to find $h$, but the answer was not in the options. The possible outcomes are: 10 ft, 11 ft, 12 ft, 13 ft, 14 ft.

I don't see what am I doing wrong. I tried the classic approach with the differentials, but I got more confused, because that path  is used when the rate in which the ladder falls is being ask, but this is not the case.

I would appreciate any help, thank you for reading.

Comment: h squared.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations look fine. When you substitute $a=\frac{59}{7}$ into the original equation, you get

$$\left(\frac{59}{7}\right)^2+100=h^2$$

$$h=\sqrt{\frac{3481}{49}+\frac{4900}{49}}=\sqrt{\frac{8381}{49}} \approx 13.08 \  \text{ft}$$

While it's not exactly $13$, the best option to select would be $13$ ft.

Comment: Well, I thought there was a way to get an exact answer, but I might have to go with this one. Thank you very much.